# When creating a login, an empty object arrives

Tags: javascript, node.js

The empty object comes to login. The use of registration, done in the similarity of the login and so everything works. By sending a request through Postman, you can register a user and check whether such one exists in the database. When you send a request for a login, instead of a token, a message comes from the last block 'else' “User with such email address not found”.

```
      const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
      const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
      const User = require('../models/User');
      const keys = require('../config/keys');

      module.exports.login = async function (req, res) {
      console.log('req.body', req.body);   //Empty object {}
      const candidate = await User.findOne({
      email: req.body.email
      });
      if (candidate) {
      const passwordResult = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, 
      candidate.password);

      if (passwordResult) {
        const token = jwt.sign({
            email: candidate.email,
            userId: candidate._id
        }, keys.jwt, {expiresIn: 60 * 60});

        res.status(200).json({
            token: `Bearer ${token}`
        })
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Passwords do not match'
        })
      }
      } else {
           console.log(req.body.email);
           console.log(candidate);
        res.status(404).json({
            message: 'User with such email address not found'
       })
       }
       };

       module.exports.register = async function (req, res) {
           console.log('req.body', req.body);
           const candidate = await User.findOne({
           email: req.body.email
       });
       if (candidate) {
       res.status(409).json({
          message: "User with this email address already exists"
       })
       } else {
          const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
          const password = req.body.password;
          const user = new User({
              email: req.body.email,
              password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
       });
          try {
              await user.save();
              res.status(201).json(user)
       } catch (e) {
       }
       }
       };
```

! [Registration works correctly] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4omHK.jpg)

! [Login does not work correctly] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrikH.jpg) "Must be token, because this user is already there"

Comment: What seems to be the problem here ?

Comment: Can you please check your req.body.email? I mean what is inside req.body.email. Is it contains the email Id you are sending from the front-end while login.

Comment: Plus.. are you sure that the user is saved in your DB after registration process?

Comment: seem you have not send proper objects from postman in login

Comment: Of course. I see all users in the database. To make no mistake, I just copy them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I use " x-form-urlencoded", the login works correctly and I get a valid token. Apparently the problem is in the internal implementation of the Postman, because the data entered with the help of "rav" should also be valid.